# Windows server 2012 R2: prevent auto log off

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, login, logoff

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 install on a remote PC (PC located in a special room) so I works on it by using remote desktop connection 
Basically, I need to download some big files (~10GB/file) but the server auto-log-off again and again each 15 minutes so I can't download anything. 
How can I prevent my server to log-off like that? 
Thanks!

update: I've tried `Run rsop.msc \ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Remote Desktop Services \ Remote Desktop Session Host \ Session Time Limits` and the setting has been disabled, what happened to me? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Group Policy, there are both Computer and User Configuration settings that may affect this. See the Computer Configuration GPOs for the server computer object and User Configuration GPOs for your user. Both are under:

\ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Remote Desktop Services \ Remote Desktop Session Host \ Session Time Limits

[image: Session Time Limits]

Check limits for both active and inactive (i.e. active but idle) connections.

---

In your updated question you indeed have S*et time limit for disconnected sessions* set to `15` minutes in a *Group Policy Object* (GPO) `Default Terminal Session TimeOut`. The options are crayed out in your *Resultant Set of Policy* (RSoP, `rsop.msc`) report – cause it's only a report.

Your options are to change this value by modifying this GPO or to create a new one that will override this setting just for you. For that, open the [Group Policy Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753298(v=ws.11).aspx) (`gpmc.msc`).

Comment: thanks for comment, I've updated on questions, please check!

Comment: My answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Run rsop.msc and check for settings configured under Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Session Time Limits.

Also see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753112(v=ws.10).aspx for further details.

Comment: thanks for comment, I've updated on questions, please check!